# Vue.js redirection to another page

Tags: vue.js, url-routing, vuejs2, vue-router

I'd like to make a redirection in `Vue.js` similar to the vanilla javascript

```
window.location.href = 'some_url'
```

How could I achieve this in Vue.js?

Comment: Do you mean a redirect to a route defined in vue router '/my/vuerouter/url'? Or do you a browser redirect to http://some-url.com?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

If you're using [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/), you can use `router.push(path)` to navigate to any particular route programmatically (note that this was `router.go(path)` prior to Vue 2).

The router itself can be accessed from the `$router` property on the Vue instance, which means that you can access `push` from within a component with `this.$router.push(path)`.

You can also use object syntax for more control, including navigating to preconfigured [named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html). From [the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location):

> ```js
> // object
> router.push({ path: 'home' })
>
> // named route
> router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: '123' } })
>
> // with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
> router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })
>
> // with hash, resulting in /about#team
> router.push({ path: '/about', hash: '#team' })
> ```

Vue router aside, `window.location.href = 'some url';` works fine for non single-page apps.

---

If you're looking for more permanent *redirection*, rather than just programmatic navigation, e.g. redirecting all `example.com/foo` hits to `example.com/bar`, then you should use [Vue Router's redirect or alias features](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html).

#### Redirect

[Redirects](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect) go in the route configuration, and let you tell Vue Router to always redirect a given path to somewhere else, e.g. navigating to `/foo` will bounce you to `/bar` instead:

```js
const routes = [{ path: '/foo', redirect: '/bar' }];
```

These paths can also be dynamic, e.g.:

```js
const routes = [{ path: '/foo/:subPath*', redirect: '/bar/:subPath*' }];
// example.com/foo/profile?id=123 --> example.com/bar/profile?id=123
```

#### Alias

[Aliases](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias) are like redirects, routing traffic from one location to another, **but they don't change the user's URL**. This gives greater flexibility by allowing you to map arbitrary parts of a UI structure to any path you desire.

From the documentation:

> ```js
> const routes = [
>   {
>     path: '/users',
>     component: UsersLayout,
>     children: [
>       // this will render the UserList component for these 3 URLs:
>       // - /users
>       // - /users/list
>       // - /people
>       { path: '', component: UserList, alias: ['/people', 'list'] },
>     ],
>   },
> ]
> ```

Comment: In my case the use is to direct to another  non single-page

Comment: I was getting : `Uncaught ReferenceError: router is not defined` error, How to inject router in component?

Comment: `this.$router.push('routename)`

Comment: ```this.$router.push({ name: 'routename' })``` works for me

Comment: So, where to put this `window.location.href` then? If we put it in mounted(), it will take a lot of time and the "original" page will flash by before redirecting. What at least I am looking for is an instant redirect with no delays, preferrably on the router directly.

Comment: @ka_lin you made a typo, I'm assuming you meant this.$router.push('routename')

Comment: I don't think the dynamic redirect works anymore, using the code above with vue router 4 you simply get redirected to the literal path `/bar/:subPath*`

Answer (score 114):

According to the docs, router.push seems like the preferred method:

> To navigate to a different URL, use router.push. This method pushes a
>   new entry into the history stack, so when the user clicks the browser
>   back button they will be taken to the previous URL.

source: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

FYI : Webpack & component setup, single page app (where you import the router through Main.js), I had to call the router functions by saying:

```
this.$router
```

Example: if you wanted to redirect to a route called "Home" after a condition is met:

```
this.$router.push('Home')
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with compilation (webpack) .

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, even though most people will be developing with the vue cli, webpack, router and store/vuex and will likely run into the problem of not being able to call the router.

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor hiyo comment na downvote utasema unamlipa haha

Comment: @Cholowao he he he , sawa tushasikia ! i got a react kazi , ping me if you got skills ...

Comment: it is clear to say `this.$router.push({name: 'router-name'})`

Answer (score 62):

just use:

```
window.location.href = "http://siwei.me"
```

Don't use vue-router, otherwise you will be redirected to 
"http://yoursite.com/#!/http://siwei.me"

my environment:  node 6.2.1, vue 1.0.21, Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't see any reason, why this should be in double quotes..?

Comment: Actually [standardjs](http://standardjs.com/) says "Use single quotes for strings except to avoid escaping."

Comment: this was some time ago but i actually i solved this by using single quotes , but i guess  double quotes should also work and might usefull in complex links .

Comment: check the vue version first. in the early version, maybe vue doesn't care the code convention. However in my environment,  code convention will cause compile error ( from es6 compiled to vanilla js ) .   If you haven't use the 'ES6' node module, maybe it will be ok.

Comment: what if you would like to open it on a new tab?

Comment: @Fthi.a.Abadi  just forget vue.js, treat the page as traditional web page, use `<a href='...' target="_blank"> ...`

Comment: SPAs should not be nuked by such navigation, bad advice. It may be okay for a new tab or an anchor navigation (if using `href`) but that's all.

Answer (score 41):

When inside a component script tag  you can use the router and do something like this

```js
this.$router.push('/url-path')
```

Answer (score 34):

if you want to route to another page use this

```js
this.$router.push({path: '/pagename'});
```

if you want to route to another page with params use this

```js
this.$router.push({
  path: '/pagename', 
  params: {
    param1: 'value1', 
    param2: 'value2'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you my hero, you saved the day! By the way, `param` didn't work, though `params` works for me.

Comment: I do on vuexy theme with
`return router.push({ name: 'publisher-slots' });`
On my form submission success area.

Answer (score 16):

**Just a dead simple routing:**

```js
this.$router.push('Home')
```

Comment: see comment by kissu to my comment regarding direct use of a simple string instead of a json wrapped name.

Answer (score 13):

can try this too ...

```js
router.push({ name: 'myRoute' })
```

Answer (score 12):

**If anyone wants permanent redirection from one page `/a` to another page `/b`**

---

We can use `redirect:` option added in the `router.js`. For example if we want to redirect the users always to a separate page when he types the root or base url `/`:

```js
const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      redirect: "/someOtherPage",
      name: "home",
      component: Home,
      // () =>
      // import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "./views/pageView/home.vue"),

    },
   ]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
window.location = url;
```

'url' is the web url you want to redirect.

Answer (score 8):

So, what I was looking for was only *where* to put the `window.location.href` and the conclusion I came to was that the best and fastest way to redirect is in routes (that way, we do not wait for anything to load before we redirect).

Like this:

```
routes: [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "ExampleRoot",
        component: exampleComponent,
        meta: {
            title: "_exampleTitle"
        },
        beforeEnter: () => {
            window.location.href = 'https://www.myurl.io';
        }
    }]
```

Maybe it will help someone..

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the v-bind directly to the template like ...

```
<a :href="'/path-to-route/' + IdVariable">
```

the `:` is the abbreviation of `v-bind`.

Comment: You can also use the ES6 Syntax: :href="`/path-to-route/${IdVariable}`" .

Answer (score 5):

this.$router.push can be used to redirect pages in vue.js

```
this.$router.push(url);
```

Example this.$router.push('home');
this method  will not refresh the pages

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Vue3 and this works for me

```
router.push({ name: 'myRoute' })
```

Comment: this is only working answer at moment.

Comment: or use `this.$router.push('/path')` if you are using composition API

Answer (score 2):

To stay in line with your original request:

```
window.location.href = 'some_url'
```

You can do something like this:

```
<div @click="this.window.location='some_url'">
</div>
```

Note that this does not take advantage of using Vue's router, but if you want to  "make a redirection in Vue.js similar to the vanilla javascript", this would work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Composition API, the approach is to use something like this

```html
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter()

router.push({ name: 'about' })
</script>
```

You can check the name of your routes by using the [Vue devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/)

[image]

I recommend using `name` too because you will not need to rewrite all the buttons/links if you want to update some path one day.

Comment: You could also combine ist with Mohammad Mahdi KouchakYazdi answer by just using `this.$router.push('about')` referencing the the name automatically.

Comment: @DirkSchumacher that pushes the string and not the route name tbh, quite different and not as flexible if you need to update your endpoints one day. While if you use a name, you can still keep your code the same from the inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="app">
   <a :href="path" />Link</a>
</div>

<script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          path: 'https://www.google.com/'
        }
      });
</script> enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Get specific page from api
The easiest way is to add another parameter to the URL that will break the cache.

> **router.replace(data.current + '?t=' + (new Date()).getTime())**

For example

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

axios
    .get('http://domazin.com/currentpage')
    .then(response => {
     const data = response.data
       if (to.path != data.current) {
              router.replace(data.current + '?t=' + (new Date()).getTime())
       } else {
          next()
       }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
});

);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Vue3.js redirect***

Vue3 js global redirect could be define using this method in main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.$redirect = (page) => {router.push(page)}
app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

Component

```
<button @click="$redirect('/login')" type="button" class="btn ">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Laravel + Inertia:
`this.$inertia.get(route('route.name', this.modelId));`