# Vue router redirect to the same path in parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is there a way to redirect any url starting with /web/* to redirect to the same url without **web**?

So a url like this:

```
https://example.com/web/page
```

would redirect to:

```
https://example.com/page
```

using Vue Router, but not declaring each redirect separately?

I know I can do it like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/web/page', redirect: '/page' }
    ]
})
```

But is there a way to just catch everything which starts with web to the same without web?

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664550/vue-js-redirection-to-another-page) I'm not sure, but it may come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to do it. 
In beforeEach the path can be checked and then corrected.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.path.startsWith('/web')) {
        next(to.path.replace('/web', ''))
    }
    ...
})
```