# Want to Redirect to URL from AXIOS GET api call in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

After Getting the AXIOS api response i need to Redirect to the url in a new tab.

Currently i am achieving this using `window.open("url")` inside the api call as like below.

```
viewimage(image) {
          Nova.request().get(`/showimage/`+image,)
              .then(response => {
                this.urlimage = response.request.responseURL;
                window.open(this.urlimage,'_blank');
               
              });
    },
```

**But i like to confirm whether its right process to use window.open("url") in axios in production environment because i am facing pop-up blocked in all browsers.**

If any other alternate way to achieve this ? Please guide me from your side.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

if you use vue-router you should use router.push("yourroutename").

Otherwise, window.location.href = 'some url'; works fine for non single-page apps.

original answer: [Vue.js redirection to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664550/vue-js-redirection-to-another-page)

Answer (score 1):

simple solution

I am using this in my project I am currently working on
this.$router.push("/this.urlimage");